# Dynamically set imageSource in ImageView Blackberry 10

Tags: c++, qt4, qml, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

Please help me.,i m stuck with this for more than a week.I am emitting a signal with image from my cpp file.I need to replace the default image that i placed in the imageView at QMl using this emitted image.
Here is my full code.

PostHttp.hpp

```
/* Copyright (c) 2012 Research In Motion Limited.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

 #ifndef POSTHTTP_HPP
 #define POSTHTTP_HPP
 #include "qvariant.h"
 #include <bb/ImageData>
 #include <bb/cascades/GroupDataModel>
 #include <QtCore/QObject>
 #include <bb/data/JsonDataAccess>
 #include <bb/cascades/QListDataModel>
 #include <bb/cascades/Image>
 #include <bb/cascades/ImageView>
 #include <bb/cascades/CustomControl>
 namespace bb {
namespace cascades {
    class Container;
}
 }
  using namespace bb::cascades;

 class QNetworkAccessManager;

class PostHttp: public QObject {
Q_OBJECT
public:
PostHttp(QObject* parent = 0);
 bb::cascades::Image m_image;
 ImageView* imageView;
 Container* mRootContainer;
 bool createFolder(QString path);
 bool openAndSaveFile(QString filePathWithName, QNetworkReply* reply);
public Q_SLOTS:
void loginWebService(const QString &body, const QString &pass,
        bool istoken);
void newsFeedWebService(const qint16 num);
void logoutWebService();
void imageFetcher();
void get(const QUrl &url);
void post(const QVariantMap &body, const QUrl &url);


Q_SIGNALS:
void complete(const QVariantList &info);
void newsfeedComplete(const QVariantList &info);
void imageLoaded(const QVariant &image);

private Q_SLOTS:
void onGetReply();
void onNewsFeedReply();
void onImageReply();

Q_INVOKABLE void generatePage();
 Q_INVOKABLE void loadImages();
private:
bb::cascades::QListDataModel<QObject*>* m_model;
QImage setImage(const QImage &image);
bb::cascades::DataModel* model() const;
QNetworkAccessManager* m_networkAccessManager;
bb::data::JsonDataAccess* dataAccess;

public:
QString token;

};

#endif
```

PostHttp.cpp

```
#include "PostHttp.hpp"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QNetworkRequest>
#include <QSslConfiguration>
#include <QUrl>
#include <bb/data/JsonDataAccess>
#include <QDateTime>
#include <bb/cascades/AbstractPane>
#include <bb/cascades/Application>
#include <bb/cascades/QmlDocument>
#include <bb/cascades/Page>
#include <bb/cascades/StandardListItem>
#include <QFile>
#include <bb/ImageData>
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QNetworkDiskCache>
#include <QDesktopServices>
#include <bb/cascades/Image>
#include <bb/cascades/Container>
#include <bb/cascades/ImageView>
#include <bb/cascades/ScalingMethod>
#include <bb/cascades/DockLayout>
#include <bb/cascades/controls/activityindicator.h>
#include <bb/cascades/controls/scrollview.h>
#include <bb/cascades/controls/page.h>
#include <bb/cascades/NavigationPaneProperties>
#include <bb/cascades/Color>
using namespace bb::data;
using namespace bb::cascades;
using namespace bb::utility;
QString globalTokenValue;
int globalUserId;
bool flag = true;
bool flag1 = true;
QVariantList data;

PostHttp::PostHttp(QObject* parent) :
    QObject(parent), m_networkAccessManager(
            new QNetworkAccessManager(this)), m_model(
            new QListDataModel<QObject*>()) {

}

//! [0]

/**
 * PostHttp::post
 *
 * Make a network request to httpbin.org/post with POST data and get
 * the response
 */
//! [1]
void PostHttp::post(const QVariantMap &body, const QUrl &url) {
JsonDataAccess jda;
QByteArray jsonData;
jda.saveToBuffer(*(&body), &jsonData);

QByteArray postDataSize = QByteArray::number(jsonData.size());
QNetworkRequest request(*(&url));

request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/json");
request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentLengthHeader,
        QString(postDataSize).toUtf8());
//QNetworkReply* reply = m_networkAccessManager->post(request, body.toAscii());
qDebug() << "json" << jsonData;
QNetworkReply* reply = m_networkAccessManager->post(request, jsonData);
qDebug() << "strdgfyusujnm kjh " << (&url)->toString();
if ((&url)->toString()
        ==    "http:///GetNewsFeed") {
    connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(onNewsFeedReply()));
} else {
    connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(onGetReply()));
}
}

void PostHttp::loginWebService(const QString &body, const QString &pass,
    bool istoken) {

qint64 date = QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch();
QString time = QString::number(date);
QVariantMap data;
QVariantMap loginData;
QVariantMap devicedata;
devicedata.insert("OS", "BlackBerry OS 6.0.0.706");
devicedata.insert("deviceId", "232BC441");
devicedata.insert("deviceModel", "9800");
devicedata.insert("screenSize", "480x360");
loginData.insert("device", devicedata);
loginData.insert("email", *(&body));
loginData.insert("password", *(&pass));
loginData.insert("requestDate", "/Date(" + time + "+200)/");
data.insert("apiKey", "4f74721be9b51f24f065b044");
data.insert("data", loginData);
data.insert("requestDate", "/Date(" + time + "+200)/");
if (istoken) {

} else {
    data.insert("token", "");
}
const QUrl url(
         "http:///LoginRequest");
post(data, url);
}

void PostHttp::newsFeedWebService(const qint16 num) {

qint64 date = QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch();
QString time = QString::number(date);
QVariantMap data;
QVariantMap newsfeedData;
newsfeedData.insert("postId", 0);
newsfeedData.insert("requestType", 2);
newsfeedData.insert("requestedCount", num);
newsfeedData.insert("userId", globalUserId);
data.insert("apiKey", "4f74721be9b51f24f065b044");
data.insert("data", newsfeedData);
data.insert("requestDate", "/Date(" + time + "+200)/");
data.insert("token", globalTokenValue);
const QUrl url(
        "http:///GetNewsFeed");
if (flag == true) {
    post(data, url);
}

}

void PostHttp::logoutWebService() {
qint64 date = QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch();
QString time = QString::number(date);
QVariantMap data;
QVariantMap logoutData;
logoutData.insert("logoutRequestType", 1);
logoutData.insert("userId", globalUserId);
data.insert("apiKey", "4f74721be9b51f24f065b044");
data.insert("data", logoutData);
data.insert("requestDate", "/Date(" + time + "+200)/");
data.insert("token", globalTokenValue);
const QUrl url(
        "http:///LogoutUser");
post(data, url);
}

void PostHttp::imageFetcher() {
const QUrl url(
        "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e7/Nuvola_filesystems_services.png");
if (flag1 == true) {
    get(url);
}
}

void PostHttp::get(const QUrl &url) {
QNetworkRequest request(*(&url));
QNetworkReply* reply = m_networkAccessManager->get(request);
connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(onImageReply()));
}
/**
 * PostHttp::onGetReply()
 *
 * SLOT
 * Read and return the http response from our http post request
 */
void PostHttp::onGetReply() {
QNetworkReply* reply = qobject_cast<QNetworkReply*>(sender());
QString response;
if (reply) {
    if (reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError) {
        const int available = reply->bytesAvailable();
        if (available > 0) {
            const QByteArray buffer(reply->readAll());
            response = QString::fromUtf8(buffer);
            JsonDataAccess dataAccess;
            QVariantMap results =
                       dataAccess.loadFromBuffer(response).toMap();
            QString token = (results["Token"]).value<QString>();
            int userId = (results["userId"]).value<int>();
            if (globalTokenValue == "") {
                globalTokenValue = token;
                globalUserId = userId;
            } else
                flag = false;
            QString success = (results["Success"]).value<QString>();

        }
    } else {
        response =
                tr("Error: %1 status: %2").arg(reply- >errorString(),
                        reply->attribute(
                                   QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute).toString());
        qDebug() << response;
    }

    reply->deleteLater();
}

if (response.trimmed().isEmpty()) {
    response = tr("Unable to retrieve post response");
}
qDebug() << "response" << response;

}

void PostHttp::onNewsFeedReply() {

QNetworkReply* reply = qobject_cast<QNetworkReply*>(sender());
QString response;
if (reply) {
    if (reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError) {
        flag = false;
        const int available = reply->bytesAvailable();
        if (available > 0) {
            const QByteArray buffer(reply->readAll());
            response = QString::fromUtf8(buffer);
            JsonDataAccess dataAccess;
            QVariantMap results =
                      dataAccess.loadFromBuffer(response).toMap();
            data = results.value("Data").toList();
            qDebug() << "first element is" << data.first().toString();
            emit newsfeedComplete(data);

        }
    }
}

}
 void PostHttp::onImageReply() {
QNetworkReply* reply = qobject_cast<QNetworkReply*>(sender());
QString response;
QImage img;
QString filePathWithName = "data/img/";
QString imageName;

if (reply) {
    if (reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError) {
        flag1 = false;
        const int available = reply->bytesAvailable();
        if (available > 0) {
            const QByteArray buffer(reply->readAll());
            response = QString::fromUtf8(buffer);
            img.loadFromData(buffer);
            img = img.scaled(40, 40, Qt::KeepAspectRatioByExpanding);
            const QImage swappedImage = img.rgbSwapped();
            const bb::ImageData imageData = bb::ImageData::fromPixels(
                    swappedImage.bits(), bb::PixelFormat::RGBX,
                    swappedImage.width(),  swappedImage.height(),
                    swappedImage.bytesPerLine());
            QByteArray byteArray = bb::utility::ImageConverter::encode(
                    "image/png", imageData, 75);
            qDebug() << "bytearray is" << byteArray;
//              QVariant image(byteArray);
            QVariant realImage(byteArray);

            qDebug() << "imag of image is" << realImage;
            emit imageLoaded(realImage);
        }
    }
}
}
//! [1]
```

And finally my QML file is

NewsFeed.qml

```
import bb.cascades 1.0
import Network.PostHttp 1.0
import bb.cascades 1.0
import "controls"
import my.library 1.0

Page {
actions: [
    ActionItem {
        title: "Logout"
        onTriggered: {
            netpost.logoutWebService();
            Application.quit();
        }
        ActionBar.placement: ActionBarPlacement.OnBar
    }
]
id:mainpage
onCreationCompleted: {
    Qt.mainImageview = imageviewid;
}
Container {

    layout: DockLayout {
    }

    // The background image
    ImageView {
        horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Fill
        verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Fill
        imageSource: "asset:///images/background.png"
    }
    //! [0]

    Container {
        id : innercontainer

        ActivityIndicator {
            id: progressIndicator

            horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Fill
            verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Fill
            onStarted: {

            }
            onCreationCompleted: {
                progressIndicator.running = true;

            }

        }

        ListView {
            id: listView
            objectName: "listView"

            dataModel: ArrayDataModel {
                id: myListModel

            }

            // Override default GroupDataModel::itemType() behaviour, which is to return item type "header"
            listItemComponents: ListItemComponent {
                id: listcomponent
                // StandardListItem is a convivience component for lists with default cascades look and feel
                StandardListItem {
                    title: ListItemData.postText
                    description: ListItemData.postDate
                    status: ListItemData.filePath
                    imageSource: "asset:///images/4.png"
                }

            }
            layoutProperties: StackLayoutProperties {
                spaceQuota: 1.0
            }
            horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Fill
            verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Fill

        }


        Container {
            id: root
            layout: StackLayout {
            }
            Label {
                text: ListItemData.postText
                horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Left
                verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Bottom
            }
            Label {
                text: ListItemData.postDate
                //                    textStyle.fontSize: 5
                horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Right
                verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Bottom
            }

            attachedObjects: [
                QTimer {
                    id: timer
                    property int f: 0
                    interval: 5000
                    onTimeout: {
                        progressIndicator.running = false;
                        netpost.imageFetcher();
                        netpost.newsFeedWebService("10");
                    }

                },
                PostHttp {

                    id: netpost
                    onComplete: {
                        progressIndicator.running = false;
                        progressIndicator.visible = false;
                        console.log("dsfdsafs"+netpost.model)
                        timer.stop();
                    }

                    onImageLoaded:{
                        console.log("value is image from cpp jhgsdh " + image)
                        imageviewid.setImageSource(image)
                    }
                    onNewsfeedComplete: {
                        console.log("response from newsfeed is "+info)
                        myListModel.append(info)

                    }
                }

            ]
        }

        onCreationCompleted: {
            // this slot is called when declarative scene is created
            // write post creation initialization here
            console.log("Page - onCreationCompleted()")

            // enable layout to adapt to the device rotation
            // don't forget to enable screen rotation in bar-bescriptor.xml (Application->Orientation->Auto-orient)
            OrientationSupport.supportedDisplayOrientation = SupportedDisplayOrientation.All;

            // populate list view model with the sample data
            timer.start();
            //                myListModel.load("app/native/assets/mydata.json")

        }
        ImageView {
            id: imageviewid
            imageSource: "asset:///images/4.png"
            enabled: true
            loadEffect: ImageViewLoadEffect.FadeZoom

        } 
    }
}
}
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: please, show the code where you define the signal, slot, and where you bind them together

Comment: I have made the edits.Please check it. Here PostHttp is the class in which signals are defined.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: So where do you connect your `imageLoaded()` signal with some slot? I can see that signal is being emitted at PostHttp.cpp:251 but which function handles this signal?

Comment: I tried to access it in the NewsFeed.qml
 onImageLoaded:{
                        console.log("value is image from cpp jhgsdh   " + image)
                        imageviewid.setImageSource(image)
                    }
Does i need to define any function.After reading signals ans slots documentation i thought than by adding 'on' before the signal name will acts as the slot and can process the parameter from signal..,am i wrong..?
Does i need to use some connect...??
If yes will you please help me with a code snippet..?

Comment: Yes, you do need to connect a signal with at least one slot if you want to use Qt signals/slots paradigm. Check out this article - https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/documentation/dev/signals_slots/ and also a tutorial - https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/documentation/dev/signals_slots/signals_slots_set_up_project.html

Comment: Thanks for your patience @Sunseeker..,
Will you please provide a sample code for how to connect my signal in the custom method in cpp to the slot 'onImageLoaded' in the QML. Because the documentation is bit confusing and not catchy..

Answer (score 1):

So you've defined your slot with `QVariant` parameter however trying to emit it with `QByteArray` type which is returned by `ImageConverter::encode()` call.

Try to change that part of your code to this and give it a go:

```
QByteArray byteArray = bb::utility::ImageConverter::encode(QUrl(QDir::currentPath() + "/shared/camera/img.png"), imageData, 75);
QVariant image(byteArray);
emit imageLoaded(image);
```

Also, double check that everywhere where you declare/define this pair of signal/slot you're specified exactly the same parameter notation (ie `const QVariant&` in case of `imageLoaded()` signal and so on)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
After implementing the above solution,got an error like this 'conversion from 'bool' to non-scalar type 'QByteArray' requested'. I think bb::utility::ImageConverter::encode(QUrl(QDir::currentPath() + "/shared/camera/img.png"), imageData, 75); returns a boolean value. So but in the documentation they said that the encode method will return an encoded image.Where is my fault?
How can i rectify this..?

Comment: This is an overloaded function, returning value depends on the parameters. Here is the documentation on this - https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb__utility__imageconverter.html Basically, you need to match the type of signal parameters with the slot ones.

Comment: Thanks Agian.,
Now i got my image like this(from terminal)
image is QVariant(QByteArray, "ÂPNG

Comment: But i couldn't place it in my ImageView.When i am trying to do so i got an error like this.,
 asset:///NewsFeed.qml:131: Error: Unknown method parameter type:
 Image

Comment: Could you please post all your code you're debugging ie QML and .cpp/.h(pp) files. As a general rule, though, I'd recommend to pass parameters between native/qml layers as pointers to `QObject` subsequently casting them to your class of interest.

Comment: Added the full code.Please check it and please point out my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this sample code and implement by re-altering in your project**

**1.QML FILE**

```
import bb.cascades 1.0

Page {
    content: Container {
        ListView {
            dataModel: _app.model

            function itemType (data, indexPath) {
                return data["type"];
            }
            listItemComponents: [

            ]
        }
    }
}
```

---

**2.HPP FILE**

```
#ifndef APP_HPP
#define APP_HPP

#include <QtCore/QObject>
#include <QtNetwork/QNetworkAccessManager>

#include <bb/cascades/QListDataModel>

class App: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    Q_PROPERTY(bb::cascades::DataModel *model READ model NOTIFY modelChanged)

public:
    App();
    bb::cascades::DataModel * model() const;

Q_SIGNALS:

    void modelChanged();

private Q_SLOTS:

    void handleNetworkData(QNetworkReply *reply);

private:

    mutable bb::cascades::QMapListDataModel *dataModel;


    QNetworkAccessManager networkManager;

};

#endif // APP_HPP
```

---

**3.CPP FILE**

```
#include <bb/cascades/Page>
#include <bb/cascades/QmlDocument>
#include <bb/data/JsonDataAccess>

#include "App.hpp"

using namespace bb::cascades;
using namespace bb::data;

App::App() :
{

    // Load up the QML for our view
    QmlDocument *qml = QmlDocument::create("view.qml");

    // Provide a reference to this class
    qml->setContextProperty("_app", this);

    // Create the root node of this view
    Page *view = qml->createRootNode<Page>();

    dataModel = new QMapListDataModel();

    // Hook this signal so we can respond to network replies
    connect(&networkManager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply *)), this,
            SLOT(handleNetworkData(QNetworkReply *)));

    // Do the request
    QUrl url = "http://jsonservice.com/news/headlines/";
    networkManager.get(QNetworkRequest(url));

}

DataModel * App::model() const
{
    return dataModel;
}

void App::handleNetworkData(QNetworkReply *reply)
{

    if (!reply->error()) {

        const QByteArray response(reply->readAll());

        JsonDataAccess jda;
        QVariantMap results = jda.loadFromBuffer(response).toMap();

        // Get the relevant parts we want from the JSON
        QVariantList posts = results["data"].toMap()["children"].toList();

        Q_FOREACH(QVariant post, posts) {


            dataModel->append(post);

        }

    }

    // Cleanup
    reply->deleteLater();

}
```

---